STM32L0 STOP mode
I'm using the STM32L0 microcontroller, and I want to activate the stop mode. Currently, when I program it with STLink, the microcontroller goes into stop mode but consumes high current. However, when I completely disconnect the power supply and reconnect it, the issue is resolved. Can anyone guide me on how to resolve this problem?
Current in STOP mode 4 uA

Is it because the MCU does not really enters STOP mode when in debug?

"Consumes high current" - be specific please. Give at least some range or an order of magnitude. 100uA? 100mA?
